# Put multiple data in one cell ASP.NET, VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

How can i put multiple data in one datagrid cell? For example, a user can be a member of different organisations.

But i dont want the table to create a new datagrid row for the same user that is a member of multiple organisations.

This is how the code looks like right now:

```
Dim dSourceMemberOf As New SqlDataAdapter("QUERY", dbConn)
```

This fills the datagrid, but for some users there are more then 5 rows. So i'd like to put for one particular column all data in one cell.

How can this be done?

Edit:

This is how it woud look like right now:

```
username    memberof 
user1       dft 
user1       kbo 
user2       test
```

And this is how i want it to looke like:

```
username   memberof 
user1      dft
           kbo 
user2      test
```

Comment: Merge it into a comma seperated list in the underlying query would be my first thought

Comment: can you give me an example? i updated the question.

Comment: you shouldn't need to change the underlying query if it is only how you display it - formatting should occur at the presentation layer

Comment: ya but if i do it like the way i do it right now, how can i have influence on how its displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is to group the data using a Linq query, then bind the grouped data to a gridview:

So the GridView would look like this:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ListBox ID="lst" runat="server" DataSource="<%# Container.DataItem.MemberOfGrouped %>" DataTextField="MemberOf"></asp:ListBox>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and here is some example code to populate it:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim UngroupedData As List(Of YourData) = New List(Of YourData)()
    Dim item1 As YourData = New YourData()
    item1.MemberOf = "dft"
    item1.UserName = "user1"
    UngroupedData.Add(item1)

    Dim item2 As YourData = New YourData()
    item2.MemberOf = "kbo"
    item2.UserName = "user1"
    UngroupedData.Add(item2)

    Dim grouped = From u In UngroupedData Group u By Key = u.UserName Into Group _
                  Select UserName = Key, MemberOfGrouped = Group.ToList()


    GridView1.DataSource = grouped
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub


Public Class YourData

    Private _userName As String
    Public Property UserName() As String
        Get
            Return _userName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _userName = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private _memberOf As String
    Public Property MemberOf() As String
        Get
            Return _memberOf
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _memberOf = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I think on paint was wrong, concept was right though - looks like you need to do it on the [databind event](http://netomatix.com/GridFormatting.aspx) event... [more here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Conditional+Formatting+Of+ASP.Net+DataGrid+Cell&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) (first three links will show you how to do what you require I think) - you could look at the row you are on, get the previous row, then decide what to do with a cell in your current row based on the prev row

Comment: looks like you want to make use of some sort of group header function, don't think you can do that on a plain .net datagrid though

Comment: you'd want to make sure sorting was off if your displaying data like that. tbh, I usually show the user multiple times, that way it's more flexible and you can create objects out of what is clicked easily (ass all your data exists on that row)

Comment: @mr shoubs, the data is only used for reference, to see who is member of what. this view isn't used for changes in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table inside the GridView-Cell (or a Listbox like Ross Scott suggested).

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:table id="TblUserGroups" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0">
    </asp:table> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

and in RowDataBound of gridview(ItemDataBound of Datagrid works similar):

```
Protected Sub Gridview1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Gridview1.RowDataBound
    Select Case e.Row.RowType
        Case DataControlRowType.DataRow
            Dim drUser As DataRowView = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
            Dim TblUserGroups As Table = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("TblUserGroups"), Table)
            Dim userID as int32 = Ctype(drUser(0), Int32)
            Dim tblGroups as DataTable = getTblUserGroups(userID) 'write a function that returns the Groups of a given User f.e. as DataTable'
            If tblGroups.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                Dim tr As New TableRow
                Dim td As New TableCell
                Dim LblNoGroup As New Label
                LblNoGroup .Text = "no user-group"
                td.CssClass = "UserWithoutGroup"
                td.Controls.Add(LblNoGroup)
                tr.Cells.Add(td)
                TblUserGroups.Rows.Add(tr)
            Else
                For Each groupRow As DataRow In tblGroups.Rows
                    Dim tr As New TableRow
                    Dim td As New TableCell
                    Dim LblGroup As New Label
                    LblGroup.Text = groupRow("GroupName").ToString 'The groups name column'
                    td.Controls.Add(LblGroup)
                    tr.Cells.Add(td)
                    TblUserGroups.Rows.Add(tr)
                Next
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

I think this is the most flexible way.